Should I take a woodworking course or invest in tools and self-study?
I’m a complete beginner to woodworking and I’m looking for advice on how to get started. I have an empty garage that I plan to use as my workspace, but I currently don’t own any tools. My background is in mathematics (I hold a PhD), so I’m comfortable with learning new skills independently through books and videos.
I’m trying to decide whether to invest in a 160-hour woodworking course, which costs $1700 USD, or to spend that money on tools and begin learning on my own in the garage.
What would you recommend for someone in my situation? Would a structured course be the best way to start, or would the money be better spent on tools and self-guided learning?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange but I've voted to close as there's no concrete or canonical answer possible and that is ideally what SE is for. All the (many many) details aside, which way to go is entirely down to the individual, meaning this is inherently subjective. Do of course feel free to stick around and ask any and all concrete questions that may come up in your woodworking journey, should research not find you suitable answers.

You'll be much better served getting input on something like this on a conventional forum, both for the valuable back and forth, but also where you can anyway expect to get responses from many more users than here (Woodworking is one of the quieter stacks). But before you ask you should search for the topic; there are definitely existing threads on this on at least two and possibly all the major woodworking fora and the existing answers may inform the subject well enough that it'll give you your answer. If you do ask it afresh, you should provide all the details that weren't included here.

Now my 2c on the basic question. I would caution that the $1,700 course is an unknown quantity to begin with — not just in terms of inherent quality but how much you will get from it, irrespective of the bona fides of any/all instructors. And caveat emptor, as not-cheap as 1.7k is, it seems suspiciously inexpensive for 160 hours. Worth bearing in mind that many skilled craftsmen are not natural teachers (a huge issue in art instruction my wife tells me, but I bet it's true across all subjects). And if it's just one guy/gal what if your characters don't mesh? That's nightmare fuel. [contd]

Now all that aside, there's an elephant in the room: no matter how good or bad the course turned out to be, afterwards you still have to buy ALL your tools.... depending on the style of woodworking you want to undertake, how big or small you want to go, the cost of the course could equate to all the tools you need (I'm being 100% literal here), or just one or two. And if you are seeking to go in entirely the opposite direction to the one I'm alluding to here (mostly hand tools), 1.7k isn't even enough to buy the single tool that most power-tool woodworkers consider the heart of the shop....

Welcome to WSE.  Unfortunately, answers to your question are likely to be opinion based rather than based upon facts. I eft it open for a day to give you some feedback, but it does not really meet the format of this Q&A site so I am closing it.  You can take the [tour] to learn more about how we work.  Moving forward, you will find this site quite helpful as questions emerge on your upcoming projects, so I encourage you to continue participating on this site.

It depends a lot on you.  How do you like to learn? on your own or be shown the way (though lots of stuff is available on line for basic info)
Both paths have plusses and minuses.  A good instructor is never a waste of time or money.  but $1700 can buy you some nice tools.
I will say generally a good class can teach you a lot of the gotcha's to avoid which can save you a lot of money on material.  If you have a cheap source of wood, go for it, if you have to buy all your wood from Home Depot, the class becomes a lot more valuable.
I've been more self taught and looking up specific questions, but I will say I have messed up a lot of projects (and learned the hard way) but I also have a mill and access to a couple hundred acres of trees to turn into lumber... so it mostly my time.

Bear in mind that you will still need to buy tools when the class is over. However, a good class (and for $1,700 it better be very good and extensive in what it covers including in expertise and duration to cover all the major tools and major joining techniques) will inform you regarding which tools first, which brands to consider, features you want in your tools, best places to get them, and how to use them safely. It will also connect you with a lot of serious woodworkers in your area which is an invaluable resource in itself. You will still dive into may online videos in the future for many projects such as how to build you own workbench or to find inspirations for your next project.
If you are committed to learning the craft, IMO take the class!

I would argue, based on the prices of many individual-subject courses run in recent years that I've seen the prices for, that $1,700 is perhaps suspiciously cheap given the number of hours. That's not to say 1.7k isn't a chunk of change, it most certainly is, but compared to a mere weekend course costing perhaps $330-$800 (!!) it makes one wonder. [Those prices are from two random weekend dovetailing courses I found just now, there'll be others that cost more I'm sure, from the likes of Cosman for example.]

Others already noted that a course can be valuable, and that whether you enjoy it or benefit from it depends on your personal preference for how to learn.
But let’s set that aside. I will argue that taking an extensive course might not be a good first step, even if you choose to do it later.
Why? There are many types of projects you might want to do (small objects, turning, furniture, carpentry). There are many styles of working (hand tools, power tools, hybrid). Each combination will require a (slightly or entirely) different set of tools, techniques, and workshop setup.
Before you tried anything, it’s hard to know what will work for you and your space. And $1700 is a huge price to find out that you hate power tools after taking a 160-hour course based on power tool woodworking (as an example).
My recommendation is to first conceive and execute a basic project with minimum tools and see what you like. If you want to start with hand tools, The Anarchist’s Tool Chest (free book) tells you all you need to know about which tools to get. For power tools, you could start with a drill and a jigsaw.
You might discover you don’t like what you thought you would. You might discover you have other needs not covered in the course (like setting up dust extraction in your shop or building a workbench). You might discover that woodworking is messy, noisy, dangerous and a health hazard. Armed with your newly gained knowledge, you can better pick the course you want, should you choose in-person instruction over continuing with books and videos.

I'd recommend spending your money on tools.  Years ago I had a cheap bandsaw and didn't realize what I would be able to do until I replaced it with a good one.  Learning on cheap tools can be a turn off, worse so if what you and the instructor do in class, you cannot then do on your own.  I would image the tools being used when the instructor is around are of high quality.
